# How to restore deleted projects in spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I deleted a project from my project explorer in spyder.I checked recycle bin or its existing directory whether I can bring it back but it isn't there.Is it possible to bring the project back or know where it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Projects that have been deleted in Spyder can't be restored at the moment, i.e. they are completely removed from the operating system.

This will be fixed in Spyder **3.0.2** (not released yet) because for this version we added the following functionality:

1. Projects deleted through Spyder won't be removed from the operating system.
2. We added a `Delete project` action to the `Projects` menu to do that. That action will delete the current project from Spyder but won't remove it from the operating system.
3. We show a warning when users try to delete a project in the Project Explorer.
4. We don't allow a project to be removed from the File Explorer.
5. We hide the project configuration directory (called `.spyproject`) from the Project and File explorers to prevent its removal.